# JQuery filter checkbox and slider

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a slider and some checkboxes that can filter the content of a certain page. I got so far that it is indeed doing what is supposed to do, but it is not memorizing what it did. So if I change the checkbox, it does indeed show the correct brand, but if I change the slider it forgets the brands and shows nothing.

**PRICE CHANGE**

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [75, 300],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val("\u20AC" + ui.values[0] + " - \u20AC" + ui.values[1]);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        alert("Stopped at " + ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/ajaxfilter/getuser.php",
            data: "amount=" + ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1] + "&amount1=" + ui.values[0] + "&amount2" + ui.values[1],
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(""+brand+"");
                $('#thumbs').html(data);
            }
        }); //end ajax
    }
});
```

**BRAND CHANGE**

```
$(".brandlist :input").click(function() {
    var brand = new Array();
    $(".brandlist input:checked").each(function() {
        brand.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/ajaxfilter/getuser.php",
        data: "brand=" + brand,
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(""+brand+"");
            $('#thumbs').html(data);
        }
    }); //end ajax
});​
```

Comment: A jsfiddle demonstrating the problem with be helpful.

Comment: What slider plugin are you using?

Comment: The standard JQUERY UI slider.

Answer (score -1):

i am also new to ajax/php. but i think as you post ajax variable. you should store in php file as in SESSION and should use session variables, so that it maintain your previous selected search option............